# Category dropdown is fetching more then the title in laravel 5 is not working

Tags: forms, laravel-5, dropdown

My category dropdown is fetching more than "title": "Arts Blog" as the value. I'm getting this in return...and I just need the $category->title only. Looking for A little help.

```
{"id":1,"title":"Arts Blog","slug":"arts-blog","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}
```

I just want the "title" as $category->title...

Here's PostsController.php

```
public function edit(Post $post)
{
    $posts = Post::with('author');

    $categories = Category::all();
    $cats = array();
        foreach ($categories as $category){
            $cats[$category->id] = $category->title;
            }

    return view('posts.edit')->withPost($post)->withCategories($cats);
}
```

edit.blade.php

```
<div class'form-group'>
{{ Form::label('category_id', 'Category :')}}
{{ Form::select('category_id', $categories, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you want to achieve. You can simplify things using Collections in Laravel.

Try this:

```
public function edit(Post $post)
{
   $categories = Category::all()->pluck('title', 'id')->toArray();
   ...
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the Form::select for the category dropdown on my edit.blade.php to get the $category->title. Right now, I'm getting all this {"id":1,"title":"Arts Blog","slug":"arts-blog","created_at":null,"updated_at":null} in my dropdown but I just want the "title". I hope this helps you understand better what I want to do.

Comment: That looks like a JSON encoded string. Try converting this to an array using PHP's `json_decode` function and then you'll get the `title` attribute.